# update text format "filtered html" on old nodes

Tags: 7, input-formats

currently i have a content type with multiple nodes, that were created with a text format of plain text. is there any way to update all these nodes to be filtered html?

/admin/config/content/formats

i changed the default format to be filtered html, by making its weight -10 it is now at the top of the list. now when a user creates a new node it will have this format but how do i convert all the old ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update the database directly using SQL queries. The queries are something like

```
UPDATE field_data_field_[example] SET field_[example]_format = '[text_format]';
UPDATE field_revision_field_[example] SET field_[example]_format = '[text_format]'
```

for a field named `field_[example]` that was created with the *Field UI* module and a text format with machine name `[text_format]`. Clear the cache afterwards.